# Orbeon, file reponsible for completed forms

Tags: persistence, orbeon

I'm looking for file which is responsible for model of completed data in xml. For example it looks like:

```
<form xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude" xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:version="java:org.orbeon.oxf.common.Version" xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0">
   <section-1>
      <control-3>name</control-3>
      <control-1>second-name</control-1>
   </section-1>
</form>
```

This example could store simple form which contains two input field (name, second-name).
I want to find it, because I want to add parameter contains id of user who complete this form. So I want to change model, to reach following effect in completed form xml:

```
<form xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude" xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:version="java:org.orbeon.oxf.common.Version" xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0">

<user-who-complete-this-form-ID>100</user-who-complete-this-form-ID>

   <section-1>
     <control-3>name</control-3>
     <control-1>second-name</control-1>
   </section-1>
</form>
```

Or maybe someone knows other way to provide id of user who complete form to own persistence layer?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the data for a form you created in Form Builder. If that is indeed the case, and you want to add a field, you can do it from Form Builder, republish the form, and the instances of the new form will have the additional field you added.

Comment: I'm integrating orbeon with my system, so I want to add 'user-id' field dynamically, to all form which will be create, in background. I've done it in FormBuilder where I send user-id as request parameter and add to form metadata in forms.xhtml and model.xml. Now I'm looking for files responsible for add user-id to completed form, similarly as I've done it in builder.

Comment: This is not "supported" out-of-the-box, but I would do this in `persistence-model.xml`, when `$mode = 'new'` https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/includes/persistence/persistence-model.xml. But you have to be careful with this type of changes, as the code there can be tricky. And of course, this file might change from version to version, and you'll need to "port" your changes forward as you upgrade. Still, I hope this helps.